# Unable to see data from repeating rows

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I am using SharePoint Online. I have a form library that uses an InfoPath form which includes a repeating section.  Previously, in SharePoint 2010, I was able to view all data entered into the repeating section in the SharePoint view. Now, after I copied the library from 2010 into SharePoint Online, only the first/top row is displayed in the view. The rest of the data entered into subsequent rows in the repeating section are only able to be seen by opening the individual form.   And of course since it is not showing in the view, it also does not get exported into Excel (which also worked in 2010).  I need to be able to export all data including all repeating rows. How can i do this in SharePoint Online?